# Apt and android library plugins

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I'm using apt plugin `com.neenbedankt.android-apt` in an android library project (`com.android.library` plugin). However aar that is built doesn't include apt generated files producing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions. Any ideas?
I've been thinking about adding generated directory as a sourceSet
, but i haven't managed to do that.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

// Idea taken from http://robertomurray.co.uk/blog/2013/gradle-android-inject-version-code-from-command-line-parameter/
def getGeneratedVersionCode = { ->
    def appVersionCode = 417
    def code = project.hasProperty('versionCode') ? versionCode.toInteger() : appVersionCode
    println "VersionCode is set to $code"
    return code
}

def getGeneratedVersionName = { ->
    def appVersionName = "0.0.1"
    def name = project.hasProperty('versionName') ? versionName : appVersionName
    println "VersionName is set to $name"
    return name
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode getGeneratedVersionCode()
        versionName getGeneratedVersionName()
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
//  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0"
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.12'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
}
```

Comment: I use Dagger2 in my library project for dependency injection and code generated in build/generated/source/apt folder is not included in aar :/

Comment: Show us your build.gradle. Refer to the docs: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt.

Comment: were you able to solve this @MarcinBak?

Comment: @amadib unfortunately no, I gave up trying, as it was not really necessary for me and I ended up delivering the source code instead of aar.

Comment: I spent hours on this issue, and was unable to resolve it, until i switched to **Project** view and saw that the generated classes were under `release` build type. After switching to `release` build type things magically started working.

I'm also using newer `annotationProcessor` from new build tools.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this by adding

> classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

into build.gradle (Project: NameOfYourProject).

full code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```